# Oracle SQL Syntax meaning

Tags: sql, oracle

I am debugging someone's Oracle/Java program that I inherited.  I know Oracle fairly well (SQL) but I ran into this sequence which confuses me.  I made generic table names but the rest is right:

```
 select min(latitude), min(longitude) from mytable.myrecord where zip like ? || '%'
```

Now this is a prepared statement so they set the "?" to "10003" to search for that zipcode in NY.  What I don't understand is the "OR" part (||).  Doesn't that mean zip is like 10003 or zip is like '%', which would match anything?

Comment: Evaluates to `zip like '10003%'`, i.e. any zip code starting with 10003.

Comment: `||` does not mean `OR`. It's the standard symbol for string concatentation.

Comment: Oh that makes sense.  I am used to Java and C programming, where it means OR ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not OR.It is string concatenation
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm